# Can we add custom attribute to the text box that get created in ag-grid edit mode?

Tags: ag-grid

We have existing grid which contains below Text box. I need to attach all those attributes to the text box that get created in ag-grid edit mode (*`<input class="ag-cell-edit-input" type="text">`* ). How can we attach the same?

```
<input typeaheadval="3" onfocus="fnborderRow(21);" onfocusout="fnborderRow(0);" type="text" id="drpClass21" vendorpaymentid="149962" vendorpaymentdetailid="167679" rowid="21" sortfieldcol="clsSortPayee" value="210 UT - Salt Lake City" selectedid="210" onchange="fnChangeObj(this);" style="border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="form-control clsSearch clsClass ui-autocomplete-input clsGLClass149962" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: What are you using, just plain javascript,Angular/React? You can create custom cell editors, see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/).

Comment: I am  using plain js . You can reproduce  using the below link https://plnkr.co/edit/0xFcBlqDgqBDwsx2Zsnv?p=preview

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to create your own custom cell editor. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dRLt5nsuaa8Fl78269KD?p=preview) is your input in a custom cell editor. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank for the same , it works now using custom cell editor

Answer (score 0):

As you're using vanilla js, you'll need to create your custom cell editor as a function, then add all the required methods to the function prototype.

Define your column def:

```
{ headerName: "Custom Input", field: "customInput", editable: true, cellEditor: 'customTextInputEditor', }
```

Create your `CustomTextInputEditor` function:

```
function CustomTextInputEditor() {

}
```

Then add all the required methods to the `CustomTextInputEditor` prototype, such as `init`:

```
CustomTextInputEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.container = createElementFromHTML('<input typeaheadval="3" onfocus="fnborderRow(21);" onfocusout="fnborderRow(0);" type="text" id="drpClass21" vendorpaymentid="149962" vendorpaymentdetailid="167679" rowid="21" sortfieldcol="clsSortPayee" value="210 UT - Salt Lake City" selectedid="210" onchange="fnChangeObj(this);" style="border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="form-control clsSearch clsClass ui-autocomplete-input clsGLClass149962" autocomplete="off">')

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".clsSearch");

        // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            params.stopEditing();
        }
    });

    var that = this;

    this.container.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        //that.onKeyDown(event)
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            //event.stopPropagation();
            params.stopEditing();
        }
    })
};
```

A full working example can found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dRLt5nsuaa8Fl78269KD?p=preview).